# Proof that a Polytope has vertices

Tags: proof-writing, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-optimization

As part of my Discrete Optimization course, I have a homework where I have to prove that a Polytope has vertices. I seems to have all tools in hand (definition of a vertex, polytop, convex hull, etc.) but I am struggling to find "where to start".

Here is what is asked :

[homework http://imageshack.com/a/img838/514/xz4y.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img838/514/xz4y.jpg)

If anyone would have hints, ideas, that would really help !

thank you

Comment: What's your definition of "vertex"? You should be able to reason inductively on the dimension of the polytope, since the vertices, however defined, ought to be the vertices of the polytope's faces. So I guess here's a possibility: show that every vertex belongs to a face, and that it is a vertex of said face. Conversely, show that any vertex of a face of the polyhedron is a vertex of the polyhedron. By induction each face will have vertices, and since every polyhedron has well defined faces, it will have vertices aswell.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Hi Olivier, thank you for your help, I have the following definition : A vector x in P (polytope) is a vertex of P if there exists some c such that c'x < c'y for all y in P, with y not equal to x. (c' meaning c transposed)

I think that your suggestion might indeed work :) I will try to dig  in this direction then, thanks :)

Comment: Related: [The number of vertices in a polytope is finite](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187431)