# The number of vertices in a polytope is finite

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, polytopes

I want to prove the following:

Let $K$ be a convex polytope. Show that $K$ has a finite number of extreme points.

I have seen the bound for the cardinality of the set of extreme points:

$|E| \leq 2$ $ n\choose 2$

I know that the $n$ comes from the number of half-spaces that form a polytope, the 2 in the binomial coefficient comes from that the extreme points are vertices, because they are in the intersection of two hyperplanes, but I dont know how to write and complete this better :)

but I dont know how to prove it, because if I prove that result I answer the above problem.

Can someone help me to prove this?

Comment: First and foremost, what definition of a convex polytope are you using?

Comment: the intersection of n convex half-spaces :)

Comment: thnks, but it does not have a answer :(

Answer (score 3):

A vertex of a $d$ dimensional polytope must be the intersection of at least $d$ of the bounding hyperplanes.  Linear algebra tells us that the intersection of fewer than that many hyperplanes must have dimension at least 1, if a point $p$ in our polytope is in such an intersection and not contained in any other hyperplanes, then we can choose a direction inside this intersection and find two points on either side of $p$ still in the polytope, hence $p$ is not extremal.

This gives the bound of $|E| \le {n \choose d}$ and we get the finiteness property you wanted.

The other bound you claim $|E| \le 2{n \choose 2}$ is false, try an $8$ dimensional hypercube.

Comment: Ok let me check this out, and Ill be back 1 hour later, thanks a lot for your help, I f i got doubts can I tell you at that hour?

Comment: Im back :), then how do you prove this result?